# work and change of kenetic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

**An object with mass 10kg lies still on a frictionless table. A force that goes from 50N to 0 in 2 seconds evenly is then applied to the object. What is the objects speed after 2 seconds.**

So i first calculated to work that is done on the object to 50J. then i used that the work done is equal to the change in kenetic energy: $1/2*m*v^2 = W$ and solved for v: $v=\sqrt((2W)/m)$ i then got 3.2 m/s which was wrong.

I did eventually solve the problem using another method, but why did this method not work?

Comment: How did you calculate the work?

Comment: i did (50*2)/2 which is the area under the force graph i think

Comment: That is wrong as dimensionally it is $force\cdot time$..!
Work is $force\cdot length$. 
Work is not easy to compute in this case as the force varies with time..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you compute the work? 
The force is changing with time evenly and by that I think they mean linearly as:
$$F(t)=F_0-{F_0/2}t$$ 
so that at $t=0$ we have $F(0)=F_0=50N$ while at $t=2$ we have $F(2)=0N$.

So we have, using Newton's law:
$$m{dv\over dt}=F_0-{F_0\over2}t$$
where $v$ is the velocity, meaning
$${dv\over dt}={F_0-{F_0\over 2}t\over m}$$
which can be easily solved separating variables as:

$$dv={F_0\over m}dt-{F_0\over 2m}tdt$$

and by integrating from 0 to $t$:

$$v(t)=v(0)+{F_0\over m}t - {F_0\over 4m}t^2$$
(note that $v(0)=0$).

Thus $v(2)={50N\over 10Kg}2s-{50N\over 4s 10Kg}4s^2=10m/s-5m/s=5m/s$

To compute work you should do (since $dx=vdt$):

$$W=\int_0^{x(2)} F(t)dx=\int_0^2F(t)v(t)dt$$

Comment: thx, and ur answer is correct. I get F=50-25x as the force graph as you wrote. But why can`t i just integrate this graph from 0 to 2 to find the work done?

Comment: I edited to answer. The force is not constant so you have to integrate.
Work is the area of the force vs DISPLACEMENT curve, not of the force vs TIME one..!

Comment: sry im an idiot:D i just realied i mixed time and distance.

Comment: still, look at my integral: while work is *ususally* the fastest thing to compute (especially when the force is constant..) in this case the integral looks a lot worse than a simple differential equation (:

Comment: @JoakimHauger Integration is a sum of all the small strips of areas under a graph. Such small area is almost a rectangle, so it is the x-axis parameter times the y-axis parameter. If you Integrate force over time, you get force times time for all the areas. This is momentum. Remember that the formula for work is $$W=F\cdot x$$so you need to multiply force with *distances* for all the areas. So you are simply looking at a wrong graph when integrating.